# Akka http server dispatcher number constantly increasing

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm testing an akka http service on AWS ECS. Each instance is added to a load balancer which regularly makes requests to a health check route. Since this is a test environment I can control for no other traffic going to the server. I notice the debug log indicating that the "default dispatcher" number is consistently increasing:

```
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:33:03.007] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41200] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:33:29.142] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41196] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:33:33.035] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41204] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:33:59.174] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41187] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:34:03.066] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41186] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:34:29.204] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41179] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
[DEBUG] [01/03/2017 22:34:33.097] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41210] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted
```

This trend is never reversed and will get up into the tens of thousands pretty soon. Is this normal behavior or indicative of an issue?

**Edit:** I've updated the log snippet to show that the dispatcher thread number goes way beyond what I would expect.

**Edit #2:** Here is the health check route code:

```
class HealthCheckRoutes()(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends LogHelper {

  val routes = pathPrefix("health-check") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      complete(OK -> "Ok")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I experience the same issue in a Play application that uses akka http. Because of this, I get an OutOfMemoryError whenever the thread count exceeds 30k , which is the max thread count allowed by the OS on EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this akka-http github issue there doesn't seem to be a problem: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/722

Answer (score 0):

Probably, yes. I think that's the thread name.

If you do [a thread dump](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178) on the server, does it have a great many open threads?

It looks like your server is leaking a thread per connection.

(It will probably be much easier to debug and diagnose this on your development machine, rather than on the EC2 VM. Try to reproduce it locally.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my fear was also the thread leak. I'll attempt to reproduce locally and do a thread dump.

Comment: Interestingly I could not reproduce locally. The default dispatcher thread number always stays below a reasonable number (~20). Perhaps this is related to the http request mechanism used by the load balancer health checks.

Answer (score 0):

For you Question, check this comment:

[Akka http server dispatcher number constantly increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402501/akka-http-server-dispatcher-number-constantly-increasing/41467091?noredirect=1#comment70318268_41467091)

About dispatcher:

It is no problem to use default dispatcher for operations like health check.

Threads are controlled by the dispatcher you specified, or **default-dispatcher** if not specified.
**default-dispatcher** is setting as following, which means the thread pool size is **between 8 to 64** or **equal to (number of processors * 3)**.

```
default-dispatcher {
  type = "Dispatcher"

  executor = "default-executor"

  default-executor {
    fallback = "fork-join-executor"
  }

  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-min = 8

    # The parallelism factor is used to determine thread pool size using the
    # following formula: ceil(available processors * factor). Resulting size
    # is then bounded by the parallelism-min and parallelism-max values.
    parallelism-factor = 3.0

    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 64

    # Setting to "FIFO" to use queue like peeking mode which "poll" or "LIFO" to use stack
    # like peeking mode which "pop".
    task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
  }
```

Dispathcer Document: 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/dispatchers.html

Configuration reference:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/general/configuration.html#akka-actor

BTW for operations take a long time and blocks other operations, here is how to specify a custom dispatcher in Akka HTTP for them:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html

Comment: The problem is that I see the default dispatcher thread number getting into the tens of thousands... for example `default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-41246`

Comment: I see. Could you paste the Akka HTTP code for the health check?

Comment: Sure, I've added the router code to my original post.

Comment: The code seems has no problem, so I guess the problem is on the ECS side. Maybe you can check active threads in the container use some monitoring tools.

Comment: Akka HTTP absolutely does _not_ work in a 1 connection, 1 thread model - that would be servlets, not Akka which is fully reactive. It multiplexes multiple connections onto a known size dispatcher, only adding threads there is it is being blocked. The thread names are that, just names, the real question is how many active threads there are. And he also mentions that the thread count remains stable and below 20 threads. It seems many threads are created and then stopped - which is how FJP works.

Comment: I deleted the sentence about connection and thread. Because I couldn't find any document about it, I check the source code of **bindAndHandle** and see the incoming connection with **sameThreadExecutionContext**. Maybe I didn't fully understand it. So could you show me somewhere to look into and figure it out?